# Electric field due to delta doping in semiconductor

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

In a lot of textbooks about semiconductors, always seem to skip the following steps. Starting from the 'delta-doped' charge distribution:

$N_D (z)= N_{D}^{2D} \delta(z-z_0)$

Where $N_{D}^{2D}$ and $z$ are the density and the location of dopants on the $z$ axis, respectively. Then the textbooks go on to say 'by Poisson's equation' we get:

$E_C (z)= 
\begin{cases}
-\frac{e^2N_{D}^{2D}}{2\epsilon} (z-z_D) \hspace{1cm} \text{for} \;\;z\leq z_D \\
+\frac{e^2N_{D}^{2D}}{2\epsilon} (z-z_D) \hspace{1cm} \text{for} \;\;z\geq z_D\\
\end{cases}$

Taking the integral of the charge distribution I get a heaviside function, which I've yet to wrangle into the anything that looks like the electric field.

Comment: I think $E_C$ stands for the "confining energy", which is the electric potential, not the electric field. Check your book once more.

Comment: Ah thank you, I think you're right - now to solve for that 2 on the denominator.

Comment: Turns out you just use Gauss' law for an infinite sheet!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you just use Gauss' law for an infinite sheet!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should probably elaborate on your answer; just because you (the questioner) understand it doesn't mean later visitors will understand it.